# Get the ID of an element within an autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the ID of an element which is

```
    <input type="text" id='4711_herstellerName' class='hersteller' />
    <input type="text" id='0815_herstellerName' class='hersteller' />
    <input type="text" id='1234_herstellerName' class='hersteller' />
```

My JQuery Part looks like this:

```
    $(".hersteller").autocomplete("ajax/getHersteller.php", {
    width: 320,
    max: 4,
    highlight: true,
    scroll: true,
    scrollHeight: 300,
    formatItem: function(data, i, n, value) {

                        alert($(this).attr('id'));

                    var herstellernummer = value.split(" ")[0];
                    var herstellername = value.replace(herstellernummer,"");

                    return herstellername.trim();
    }
});
```

What I want is an alert box with the content of "4711_herstellerName" (when I change the first input), and "1234_herstellerName" (when I change the last one), but all I get is "undefined" ... I am obviously misinterpreting the documentation. Can some kind soul give me a direction?

Maybe there is another way of doing what I need: The edit in this field (and subsequient select) should change values (that are all delivered by the php script) in different input fields. All these field IDs are created automatically, but all fields of one group are beginning with the same ID in the form

- [pid]_herstellerID
- [pid]_herstellerName (this is the one I that gets autocompleted
- [pid]_herstellerLogo

What I am trying to do is get the ID from which the autocomplete has changed, slice off the pid-part, and create the herstellerID and herstellerLogo id names...

- **EDIT 1** Changed Code to make my problem clearer
- **EDIT 2** Added what I originally wanted to achieve

Comment: try this [JQuery Autocomplete Event-Select](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select)

Comment: You have some formatting issues there.

Comment: @Noma What does the "select" event have to do with it? How do you propose that the OP use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ipr101's right: jQuery Autocomplete does not set `this` to the object for which you're providing autocomplete formatting rules.

`this` is instead merely whatever it was outside of the function expression. So, if you set up the surrounding context properly, you can probably make it work:

```
$(".hersteller").each(function() {
   var $obj = $(this);
   $obj.autocomplete("ajax/getHersteller.php", {
      width:        320,
      max:          4,
      highlight:    true,
      scroll:       true,
      scrollHeight: 300,
      formatItem:   function(data, i, n, value) {
         alert($obj.attr('id'));

         var herstellernummer = value.split(" ")[0];
         var herstellername = value.replace(herstellernummer,"");

         return herstellername.trim();
      }
   });
});
```

<sup>(Untested but logical)</sup>

Comment: That is working greatly :) You are a gentleman and a scholar :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the 'this' reference in your callback will not refer to the ".hersteller" textbox; try this -

```
alert($(".hersteller").attr('id'));
```

Comment: This works fine - as long as I only have one field in the class hersteller - unfortunately, I can have several (that's the reason for using classes in the first place :) )  Thanks for your input, nontheless